# Почему Telegram-бот не читает данные из файла?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Идея бота: Юзер вводит дату, а бот выдает праздник в этот день. В отдельном файлике лежит словарь, где дата - ключ, описание праздника - значение. Проблема в том, что бот не читает данные из файлика. Он поочерёдно выводит вот эти два захардкоженных сообщения. Как это исправить?

```
def func(message):
    if message.text == "":
       bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, slovar.data_year.get(""))
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "В этот день праздников нет. Иди работать!")


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    data = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Введите дату в формате Д.ММ и нажмите ENTER")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(data, func)


bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что значит "не лезет в файлик"? Где у вас в коде открытие и чтение из файла?

Comment: @ insolor slovar.data_year.get в консоли локально эта команда работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С учетом ответа автора, думаю должно быть так:

```
def func(message):
    text = message.text
    holidays = slovar.data_year.get(text)
    if holidays:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, holidays)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "В этот день праздников нет. Иди работать!")
```

А лучше так (`get` вернет второе значение, если ключа не будет в словаре):

```
def func(message):
    text = message.text
    result = slovar.data_year.get(text, "В этот день праздников нет. Иди работать!")
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, result)
```

---

**UPD.** Дублирование сообщений, показанных в вопросе, не повторилось.

[Пример:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/a9d9c37d9a4ed83d23c89d8eaa455f6f1397669c/telegram_bot__telethon__examples/register_next_step_handler.py#L22)

```
import telebot
from config import TOKEN


bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

data_year = {
    '01.01': 'Новый год',
    '23.02': '23 февраля',
}


def func(message):
    text = message.text
    result = data_year.get(text, "В этот день праздников нет. Иди работать!")
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, result)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    data = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Введите дату в формате Д.ММ и нажмите ENTER")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(data, func)


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое! Вот только при дате например 29.02 (её нет в словаре) пишет не ошибку "В этот день праздников нет. Иди работать!", а "Введите дату в формате Д.ММ и нажмите ENTER". и при каждом перезапуске бота, он эти фразы почему-то чередует

Comment: @СергейБогданов, у меня проблем с этим не было. Если у вас такой же код как в моем ответе вызывает эту проблему, возможно это бага в библиотеке... А вы порядок соблюдаете? 1) Сначала вводите любой текст, вызывается функция get_text_messages и выводится сообщение `Введите дату в формате ...`, 2) Вводите дату, вызывается func 3) Пользователю показывается сообщение из словаря, если есть ключ, иначе `В этот день ...`

Comment: @ gil9red Вот как происходит: Запускаю бота. выводит Введите дату в формате ... ввожу. Опять то же, снова ввожу дату, берет из словаря. Ввожу другую дату, опять Введите дату в формате ... и так далее... Он чередует эту фразу с выводом из словаря на любую дату.

Comment: @ gil9red добавил скрин к ответу

Comment: @СергейБогданов, не надо в мой ответ добавлять ваши скриншоты :) Вы можете вставить в вопрос/ответ скриншот и скопировать ссылку на картинку, а ее уже прикладывать к комментарию. Да и от скриншотов тут мало пользы, по ним ведь сложно понять что у вас в коде происходит. Сделайте лучше отдельный вопрос и добавьте в него [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @ gil9red ок. Спасибо за советы

Answer (score 0):

добавить в func вот так:

```
send = message.text
    if message.text == send:
       bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, slovar.data_year.get(send))
```

Comment: `send = message.text` и `if message.text == send:` всегда True, т.к. в `send` будет значение `message.text`. Проверку уберите

Comment: Другими словами, у вас не работало, т.к. в коде вопросы вы запрашивали по пустому ключу: `slovar.data_year.get("")`, а теперь вы туда передаете текст сообщения от пользователя: `slovar.data_year.get(send)`

Comment: @ gil9red Верно. Он просто перебирал две системных фразы. а сейчас нормально лезет в словарь и достаёт необходимое

Comment: Убрал ненужную проверку из кода. Но есть замечание. Я в виде ответа покажу

Comment: @ gil9red  Бот ответы дублировать начал

Comment: При том коде не должно, либо у вас там что-то такое намешано... Вернул изменения, а вы посмотрите мой ответ :)

Comment: @ gil9red Добавил скрин в свой вопрос. вот какая реакция

Comment: Видно, что теперь правильно достает значение из словаря, но то дублирование... это вопрос к самому telebot и к работе с register_next_step_handler, я на нем не пишу, поэтому так сразу и не скажу как правильно сделать. С другой стороны, на ваш вопрос уже есть ответ, поэтому предлагаю по этому дублированию сделать отдельный вопрос, добавьте туда минимальный код для воспроизведения ошибки :)

Comment: Повторил код из вопроса и проблема не повторилась. Добавлю в свой ответ